# How to read and save attachments using node-imap

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, imap

I'm using [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) and I can't find a straightforward code example of how to save attachments from emails fetched using [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) to disk using fs.

I've read the documentation a couple of times. It appears to me I should do another fetch with a reference to the specific part of a message being the attachment. I started of with the basic example:

```
var Imap = require('imap'),
    inspect = require('util').inspect;

var imap = new Imap({
  user: 'mygmailname@gmail.com',
  password: 'mygmailpassword',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true
});

function openInbox(cb) {
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
  openInbox(function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:3', {
      bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)',
      struct: true
    });
    f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
      console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
      var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
      msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
        var buffer = '';
        stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
          buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });
        stream.once('end', function() {
          console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer)));
        });
      });
      msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
        console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));

        //Here's were I imagine to need to do another fetch for the content of the message part...

      });
      msg.once('end', function() {
        console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
      });
    });
    f.once('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
    });
    f.once('end', function() {
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
      imap.end();
    });
  });
});

imap.once('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

imap.once('end', function() {
  console.log('Connection ended');
});

imap.connect();
```

And this example works. This is the output with the attachment part:

```
 [ { partID: '2',
     type: 'application',
     subtype: 'octet-stream',
     params: { name: 'my-file.txt' },
     id: null,
     description: null,
     encoding: 'BASE64',
     size: 44952,
     md5: null,
     disposition:
      { type: 'ATTACHMENT',
        params: { filename: 'my-file.txt' } },
     language: null } ],
```

How do I read that file and save it to disk using node's fs module?

Comment: The partID you see, 2 in your example, is the part number. You want to issue UID FETCH 1234 BINARY.PEEK[2] (if the server supports the BINARY extension) or BODY.PEEK[2]. BINARY.PEEK gives you the raw data, BODY.PEEK has to be decoded according to the encoding field you also have. At this point you have a string in RAM, and I expect you can find a way to write that string to a file using node.js.

Comment: @arnt Thanks. How does the first parameter of `imap.seq.fetch` look like to make it do `UID FETCH 1234 BINARY.PEEK[2]`? And Yes, I know how to stream and decode that to file. I'm going to use [base64-stream](https://github.com/mazira/base64-stream) for that.

Comment: The first argument to imap.seq.fetch is the UID, so it's a single number if you want to download (one part of) a single message. I suppose it's just '5' in your example. '5:*' means 'all messages from 5 to the last message in the mailbox, inclusive'.

Comment: @arnt Yes that was it! I tried that before, but appears that I also need to do `imap.fetch` with the secondary request as opposed to 'imap.seq.fetch' with the primary fetch. If you like you can formulate  an answer here, if not, I'll do it myself so to help others.

Comment: Then imap.seq.fetch probably uses MSNs instead of UIDs. The message with the lowest UID has MSN 1, the one with the second-lowest UID has MSN 2, and so on. MSNs change. When in doubt, stick to UIDs and avoid MSNs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to help of @arnt and [mscdex](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap/issues/407). Here's a complete and working script that streams all attachments as files to disk while base64 decoding them on the fly. Pretty scalable in terms of memory usage.

```
var inspect = require('util').inspect;
var fs      = require('fs');
var base64  = require('base64-stream');
var Imap    = require('imap');
var imap    = new Imap({
  user: 'mygmailname@gmail.com',
  password: 'mygmailpassword',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true
  //,debug: function(msg){console.log('imap:', msg);}
});

function toUpper(thing) { return thing && thing.toUpperCase ? thing.toUpperCase() : thing;}

function findAttachmentParts(struct, attachments) {
  attachments = attachments ||  [];
  for (var i = 0, len = struct.length, r; i < len; ++i) {
    if (Array.isArray(struct[i])) {
      findAttachmentParts(struct[i], attachments);
    } else {
      if (struct[i].disposition && ['INLINE', 'ATTACHMENT'].indexOf(toUpper(struct[i].disposition.type)) > -1) {
        attachments.push(struct[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return attachments;
}

function buildAttMessageFunction(attachment) {
  var filename = attachment.params.name;
  var encoding = attachment.encoding;

  return function (msg, seqno) {
    var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
    msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
      //Create a write stream so that we can stream the attachment to file;
      console.log(prefix + 'Streaming this attachment to file', filename, info);
      var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
      writeStream.on('finish', function() {
        console.log(prefix + 'Done writing to file %s', filename);
      });

      //stream.pipe(writeStream); this would write base64 data to the file.
      //so we decode during streaming using 
      if (toUpper(encoding) === 'BASE64') {
        //the stream is base64 encoded, so here the stream is decode on the fly and piped to the write stream (file)
        stream.pipe(base64.decode()).pipe(writeStream);
      } else  {
        //here we have none or some other decoding streamed directly to the file which renders it useless probably
        stream.pipe(writeStream);
      }
    });
    msg.once('end', function() {
      console.log(prefix + 'Finished attachment %s', filename);
    });
  };
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:3', {
      bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)'],
      struct: true
    });
    f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {
      console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
      var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
      msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
        var buffer = '';
        stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
          buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });
        stream.once('end', function() {
          console.log(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', Imap.parseHeader(buffer));
        });
      });
      msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
        var attachments = findAttachmentParts(attrs.struct);
        console.log(prefix + 'Has attachments: %d', attachments.length);
        for (var i = 0, len=attachments.length ; i < len; ++i) {
          var attachment = attachments[i];
          /*This is how each attachment looks like {
              partID: '2',
              type: 'application',
              subtype: 'octet-stream',
              params: { name: 'file-name.ext' },
              id: null,
              description: null,
              encoding: 'BASE64',
              size: 44952,
              md5: null,
              disposition: { type: 'ATTACHMENT', params: { filename: 'file-name.ext' } },
              language: null
            }
          */
          console.log(prefix + 'Fetching attachment %s', attachment.params.name);
          var f = imap.fetch(attrs.uid , { //do not use imap.seq.fetch here
            bodies: [attachment.partID],
            struct: true
          });
          //build function to process attachment message
          f.on('message', buildAttMessageFunction(attachment));
        }
      });
      msg.once('end', function() {
        console.log(prefix + 'Finished email');
      });
    });
    f.once('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
    });
    f.once('end', function() {
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
      imap.end();
    });
  });
});

imap.once('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

imap.once('end', function() {
  console.log('Connection ended');
});

imap.connect();
```

Comment: any idea how to get messages for draft, sent and other folders or all the folders at once. Would be really helpful thanks

Comment: Go look for how to read those folders via IMAP in general. Then combine whatever you find with my answer. I found this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/201346/122588 . What if in my answer you replace INBOX with ALL? Might not work, but it gives you an idea about the process of getting what you want.

Comment: be aware of case comparing, 'cause in my case, all attributes in response object had only lowercase values, but in example all in uppercase. Moreover `if (struct[i].disposition && ['INLINE', 'ATTACHMENT'].indexOf(struct[i].disposition.type) > -1) {
        attachments.push(struct[i]);
      }` must be changed to

 `if (struct[i].disposition && (['ATTACHMENT'].indexOf(struct[i].disposition.type) > -1||['attachment'].indexOf(struct[i].disposition.type) > -1)) {
        attachments.push(struct[i]);
      }`

Comment: @Vladuysha added safe case comparing. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I got a minor problem in fetching the attachments. I introduced a new variable af instead of f when fetching the attachments and calling buildAttMessageFunction(). However, unfortunately the af.on('message', ...) callback is never executed. Did anyone else have this issue? I tried to debug the lib by looking at the commands --> by using plain telnet it works! Just the callback is somehow not called/message-event not fired

Comment: Getting error 

> base64.decode is not a function

Comment: Found the solution for base64.decode is not a function, just replace the line with > stream.pipe(new base64.Base64Decode()).pipe(writeStream);

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this its work for me.for gmail.

```
const IMAP = require("imap");
const MailParser = require("mailparser").MailParser;
const moment = require('moment');
var fs = require('fs'), fileStream;
module.exports.imapEmailDownload = function () {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const imapConfig = {
            user: 'XXX126@gmail.com',
            password: 'XXX@126',
            host: 'imap.gmail.com',
            port: '993',
            tls: true,
            tlsOptions: {
                secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'
            }
        }
        const imap = IMAP(imapConfig);

        imap.once("ready", execute);
        imap.once("error", function (err) {
            console.error("Connection error: " + err.stack);
        });

        imap.connect();

        function execute() {
            imap.openBox("INBOX", false, function (err, mailBox) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }
                imap.search([["ON", moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')]], function (err, results) {
                    if (!results || !results.length) { console.log("No unread mails"); imap.end(); return; }
                    /* mark as seen
                    imap.setFlags(results, ['\\Seen'], function(err) {
                        if (!err) {
                            console.log("marked as read");
                        } else {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                        }
                    });*/
                    var f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: "" });
                    f.on("message", processMessage);
                    f.once("error", function (err) {
                        return Promise.reject(err);
                    });
                    f.once("end", function () {
                        imap.end();
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        function processMessage(msg, seqno) {
          
            var parser = new MailParser({ streamAttachments: true });
            parser.on("headers", function (headers) {
            });

            parser.on('data', data => {
                if (data.type === 'text') {
                    console.log(seqno);
                    console.log(data.text);  /* data.html*/
                }

            });
            let data = ""
            msg.on("body", function (stream) {
                stream.on("data", function (chunk) {
                    data = data + chunk.toString("utf8");
                    parser.write(chunk.toString("utf8"));
                });
                stream.on("end", (chunk) => {
                })
            });

            parser.on('attachment', async function (attachment, mail) {
                let filepath = './download/';
                let output = fs.createWriteStream(filepath + attachment.fileName);
                
                attachment.stream.pipe(output).on("end", function () {
                    console.log("All the data in the file has been read");
                }).on("close", function (err) {
                    console.log("Stream has been cloesd.");
                });

            });

            msg.once("end", function () {
                // console.log("Finished msg #" + seqno);
                parser.end();
            });
        }
        resolve();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        reject(error);
    }
});};
```

Answer (score 1):

based Christiaan Westerbeek

changed:  1. use =>, forEach; 2. the 2nd fetch don't need "struct".

Problem:

In some cases, the attachment's filename SHOLUD be attachment.disposition.params['filename*']. Please see "RFC2231 MIME Parameter Value and Encoded Word Extensions" & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327954/how-to-decode-attachment-filename-in-javascript).

```
const fs = require('fs')
const base64 = require('base64-stream')
const Imap = require('imap')

const imap = new Imap({
  user: 'XXX@126.com',
  password: 'XXXXX',
  host: 'imap.126.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true /*,
  debug: (msg) => {console.log('imap:', msg);} */
});

function toUpper(thing) { return thing && thing.toUpperCase ? thing.toUpperCase() : thing }

function findAttachmentParts(struct, attachments) {
  attachments = attachments ||  []
  struct.forEach((i) => {
    if (Array.isArray(i)) findAttachmentParts(i, attachments)
    else if (i.disposition && ['INLINE', 'ATTACHMENT'].indexOf(toUpper(i.disposition.type)) > -1) {
      attachments.push(i)
    }
  })
  return attachments
}

imap.once('ready', () => {
  // A4 EXAMINE "INBOX"
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, (err, box) => { 
    if (err) throw err;
    // A5 FETCH 1:3 (UID FLAGS INTERNALDATE BODYSTRUCTURE BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT DATE)])
    const f = imap.seq.fetch('1:3', {
      bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)'],
      struct: true  // BODYSTRUCTURE
    }) 
    f.on('message', (msg, seqno) => {
      console.log('Message #%d', seqno)
      const prefix = `(#${seqno})`
      var header = null
      msg.on('body', (stream, info) => {
        var buffer = ''
        stream.on('data', (chunk) => { buffer += chunk.toString('utf8') });
        stream.once('end', () => { header = Imap.parseHeader(buffer) })
      });
      msg.once('attributes', (attrs) => {
        const attachments = findAttachmentParts(attrs.struct);
        console.log(`${prefix} uid=${attrs.uid} Has attachments: ${attachments.length}`);
        attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
        /* 
          RFC2184 MIME Parameter Value and Encoded Word Extensions
                  4.Parameter Value Character Set and Language Information
          RFC2231 Obsoletes: 2184
          {
            partID: "2",
            type: "image",
            subtype: "jpeg",
            params: {
    X         "name":"________20.jpg",
              "x-apple-part-url":"8C33222D-8ED9-4B10-B05D-0E028DEDA92A"
            },
            id: null,
            description: null,
            encoding: "base64",
            size: 351314,
            md5: null,
            disposition: {
              type: "inline",
              params: {
    V           "filename*":"GB2312''%B2%E2%CA%D4%B8%BD%BC%FE%D2%BB%5F.jpg"
              }
            },
            language: null
          }   */            
          console.log(`${prefix} Fetching attachment $(attachment.params.name)`)
          console.log(attachment.disposition.params["filename*"])
          const filename = attachment.params.name  // need decode disposition.params['filename*'] !!!
          const encoding = toUpper(attachment.encoding)
          // A6 UID FETCH {attrs.uid} (UID FLAGS INTERNALDATE BODY.PEEK[{attachment.partID}])
          const f = imap.fetch(attrs.uid, { bodies: [attachment.partID] })
          f.on('message', (msg, seqno) => {
            const prefix = `(#${seqno})`
            msg.on('body', (stream, info) => {
              const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
              writeStream.on('finish', () => { console.log(`${prefix} Done writing to file ${filename}`) })
              if (encoding === 'BASE64') stream.pipe(base64.decode()).pipe(writeStream)
              else stream.pipe(writeStream)
            })
            msg.once('end', () => { console.log(`${prefix} Finished attachment file${filename}`) })
          })
          f.once('end', () => { console.log('WS: downloder finish') })
        })
      })
      msg.once('end', () => { console.log(`${prefix} Finished email`); })
    });
    f.once('error', (err) => { console.log(`Fetch error: ${err}`) })
    f.once('end', () => {
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!')
      imap.end()
    })
  })
})
imap.once('error', (err) => { console.log(err) })
imap.once('end', () => { console.log('Connection ended') })
imap.connect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is updated instead of using **pipe** method you could directly use this approach to write your file.
`

```
    const Imap = require("imap")
const fs = require("fs")
const { simpleParser } = require("mailparser")
      const imapConfig = {
      user: "your mail",
      password: "your password",
      host: "imap.gmail.com",
      port: 993,
      tls: true,
      tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    }
    
    const getEmails = () => {
      try {
        
        const imap = new Imap(imapConfig)
        imap.once("ready", () => {
          imap.openBox("INBOX", false, () => {
            //to fetch latest 25 emails
            const currentDate = new Date()
            const daysAgo = 25
            const sinceDate = new Date(currentDate)
            sinceDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - daysAgo)
            imap.search([["SINCE", sinceDate]], (err, result) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error("Error while searching for messages:", err)
                imap.end()
                return
              }
              if (result.length === 0) {
                console.log("No messages to fetch.")
                imap.end()
                return
              }
              const mails = imap.fetch(result, { bodies: "" })
              console.log("Fetching emails...")
              mails.on("message", (msg) => {
                let attachments = []
                msg.on("body", (stream) => {
                  simpleParser(stream, async (err, parsed) => {
                   
                    if (err) {
                      console.log("Error while parsing", err)
                    } else {
                      attachments = parsed.attachments || []
                      // console.log("Subject:", parsed.subject)
                      // console.log("Text body:", parsed.text)
                      // console.log("attachments:", attachments)
                      if (attachments.length) {
                        attachments.forEach((attachment, index) => {
                          if (attachment?.contentType === "application/pdf") {
                            console.log("pdf file found", attachment.content)
                            let fileName = attachment?.filename
                            fileName = fileName.replace(".docx", "")
                            console.log("fileName", fileName)
                            const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(
                              `./attachments/attachment_${index}_${fileName}`,
                              { encoding: "binary" }
                            )
                            fileStream.write(attachment.content)
    
                            // Close the file stream
                            fileStream.end()
                            
                            fileStream.on("finish", () => {
                              console.log(` Done writing to file ${fileName}`)
                            })
                          }
                        })
                      }
                    }
                  })
                })
                msg.once("attributes", (attrs) => {
                  const { uid } = attrs
                  // imap.addFlags(uid, ["\\Seen"], () => {
                  //   console.log("Here Marked as read")
                  // })
                })
              })
              mails.once("error", (ex) => {
                return Promise.reject(ex)
              })
              mails.once("end", () => {
                console.log("Done fetching all messages!")
                imap.end()
              })
            })
          })
        })
        imap.once("error", (err) => {
          console.log("error:", err)
        })
    
        imap.once("end", () => {
          console.log("Connection ended")
        })
    
        imap.connect()
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error while getting the email:-", error)
      }
    }
    getEmails()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The below explanation is for downloading attachments from Emails, also there a flag (markAsRead) set it true to read only UNREAD mails, ans false for downloading all attachments.

Fetching only unread/unseen emails: you have to wrap the fetching call in the callback for a search one, like this:

```
 imap.search(
      ['UNSEEN'],
      function(err, results) {
          // current code
      }
);
```

Marking emails as read: was a tricky one for me, at line 53, the call to open the inbox is something like this:
imap.openBox('INBOX', true, function(err, box) {
the second parameter (the true value) is for opening the inbox in readonly mode. You need to change it to false and then, add a field markSeen: true in the second parameter:

```
var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:*', {
      bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)'],
      struct: true,
      markSeen: true // <---- this is new
});
```

So, this is the script I'm using right now, changes are:

Mark mails as read: if the config option imapOptions.markAsRead is set to true it will mark processed mails as read.
Filename Format: there is a config option (downloads.filenameFormat) that can be used to rename files. It's really simple. If you set it to $FILENAME or just remove it, it will keep the original file name. I included it because people are sending files named the same, but with different content and I need to keep them all.
Logs: I've added logs using the simple-node-logger package. The scripts uses two levels: debug which shows everything from the original script and info which are simpler logs. Also uses the error level in case you only need that.

```
const config = require('./config.json');
const markAsRead = (config.imapOptions && config.imapOptions.markAsRead) ? config.imapOptions.markAsRead : false;

const fs = require('fs');
const { Base64Decode } = require('base64-stream')

const Imap = require('imap');
const imap = new Imap(config.imap);

// Simple logger:
const logger = require('simple-node-logger').createSimpleLogger( config.logs?.simpleNodeLogger || { logFilePath:'mail-downloader.log', timestampFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS' } );
logger.setLevel(config.logs?.level || 'debug');

// var emailDate;
// var emailFrom;
function formatFilename(filename, emailFrom, emailDate) {
  // defaults to current filename:
  let name = filename;
  // if custom config is present:
  if (config.downloads) {
    // if format provided, use it to build filename:
    if (config.downloads.filenameFormat) {
      name = config.downloads.filenameFormat;
      // converts from field from "Full Name <fullname@mydomain.com>" into "fullname":
      name = name.replace('$FROM', emailFrom.replace(/.*</i, '').replace('>', '').replace(/@.*/i, ''));
      // parses text date and uses timestamp:
      name = name.replace('$DATE', new Date(emailDate).getTime());
      name = name.replace('$FILENAME', filename);
    }
    // if directory provided, use it:
    if (config.downloads.directory) name = `${config.downloads.directory}/${name}`;
  }
  // return formatted filename:
  return name;
}

function findAttachmentParts(struct, attachments) {
  attachments = attachments ||  [];
  for (var i = 0, len = struct.length, r; i < len; ++i) {
    if (Array.isArray(struct[i])) {
      findAttachmentParts(struct[i], attachments);
    } else {
      if (struct[i].disposition && ['inline', 'attachment'].indexOf(struct[i].disposition.type.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        attachments.push(struct[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return attachments;
}

function buildAttMessageFunction(attachment, emailFrom, emailDate) {
  const filename = attachment.params.name;
  const encoding = attachment.encoding;

  return function (msg, seqno) {
    var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
    msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
      //Create a write stream so that we can stream the attachment to file;
      logger.debug(prefix + 'Streaming this attachment to file', filename, info);
      var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(formatFilename(filename, emailFrom, emailDate));
      writeStream.on('finish', function() {
        logger.debug(prefix + 'Done writing to file %s', filename);
      });

      //so we decode during streaming using 
      if (encoding.toLowerCase() === 'base64') {
        //the stream is base64 encoded, so here the stream is decode on the fly and piped to the write stream (file)
        stream.pipe(new Base64Decode()).pipe(writeStream)
      } else  {
        //here we have none or some other decoding streamed directly to the file which renders it useless probably
        stream.pipe(writeStream);
      }
    });
    msg.once('end', function() {
      logger.debug(prefix + 'Finished attachment %s', filename);
      logger.info(`Attachment downloaded: ${filename}`)
    });
  };
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
  logger.info('Connected');
  imap.openBox('INBOX', !markAsRead, function(err, box) {

    if (err) throw err;
    imap.search(
      ['UNSEEN'],
      function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!results.length) {
          // if now unread messages, log and end connection:
          logger.info('No new emails found');
          imap.end();

        } else {
          logger.info(`Found ${results.length} unread emails`)
          // if unread messages, fetch and process:
          var f = imap.fetch(results, {
            bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)'],
            struct: true,
            markSeen: markAsRead
          });
  
          f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {
            logger.debug('Message #%d', seqno);
            const prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';

            var emailDate;
            var emailFrom;

            msg.on(
              'body',
              function(stream, info) {
                var buffer = '';
                stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                  buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
                });
                stream.once('end', function() {
                  const parsedHeader = Imap.parseHeader(buffer);
                  logger.debug(prefix + 'Parsed header: %s', parsedHeader);
                  // set to global vars so they can be used later to format filename:
                  emailFrom = parsedHeader.from[0];
                  emailDate = parsedHeader.date[0];
                  logger.info(`Email from ${emailFrom} with date ${emailDate}`);
                });
              }
            );
      
            msg.once(
              'attributes',
              function(attrs) {
                const attachments = findAttachmentParts(attrs.struct);
                logger.debug(prefix + 'Has attachments: %d', attachments.length);
                logger.info(`Email with ${attachments.length} attachemnts`);
                for (var i = 0, len=attachments.length ; i < len; ++i) {
                  const attachment = attachments[i];
                  logger.debug(prefix + 'Fetching attachment %s', attachment.params.name);
                  var f = imap.fetch(attrs.uid , {
                    bodies: [attachment.partID],
                    struct: true
                  });
                  //build function to process attachment message
                  f.on('message', buildAttMessageFunction(attachment, emailFrom, emailDate));
                }
              }
            );
      
            msg.once(
              'end',
              function() {
                logger.debug(prefix + 'Finished email');
              }
            );
          });
      
          f.once('error', function(err) {
            logger.error('Fetch error: ' + err);
          });
      
          f.once('end', function() {
            logger.info('Done fetching all messages!');
            imap.end();
          });

        }

      }
    );

  });
});

imap.once('error', function(err) {
  logger.error(err);
});

imap.once('end', function() {
  logger.info('Connection ended');
});

imap.connect();
```

and this is the config file with the new options:

```
{
  "imap": {
    "user": "myuser@maydomain.com",
    "password": "myPassword",
    "host": "myImapServer",
    "port": 993,
    "tls": true
  },
  "imapOptions": {
    "markAsRead": false
  },
  "downloads": {
    "directory": "./downloads",
    "filenameFormat": "$DATE_$FROM_$FILENAME"
  },
  "logs": {
    "level": "info",
    "simpleNodeLogger": {
      "logFilePath": "mail-downloader.log",
      "timestampFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080402/fetching-all-unseen-email-body-attachment-with-node-imap/71854748#71854748 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236079/node-imap-how-to-find-and-save-emails-and-their-attachments/71854648#71854648

Comment: Actually this was my first answer, 
I will take care of this in future.
And also the solution is pretty amazing :D

Comment: "this was my first answer" would be more plausible if you only commented it on a single post...