# Node Imap - How to find and save emails and their attachments

Tags: node.js, download, imap, attachment

While using this module [Node imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) I wonder how to download not only the emails but also the attachments. Nowhere to be found some simple example that shows how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read and save attachments using node-imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247207/how-to-read-and-save-attachments-using-node-imap)

Answer (score 0):

Based on an example provided by the module author, I managed to put together some code that fetches the unread messages and then gets the content plus the attachments.
Couldn't find a full example of what I needed anywhere; It's far from perfect, I have some trouble dealing with async processes, so it can certainly be improved.

Hope it's of some use to somebody

[Code in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7iPrsY5Y)