# Node.js IMAP client - "SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number" error when connecting to Hetzner mail server using "imap-simple" package

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, imap

I want to fetch all E-Mails from a Hetzner Mail.
I think they support TLS1.2 https://docs.hetzner.com/konsoleh/account-management/email/setting-up-an-email-account/
I use the npm package "imap-simple". I get error:"ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER".

I tried setting secureProtocol option to "TLS_method", not defining the version which should allow the client to negotiate the highest version of TLS that is supported by the server but  keep getting the same error.

My Code so far:

```
const imaps = require('imap-simple');

const config = {
 imap: {
   user: 'mysecret@email.com',
   password: 'mysecretpassword',
   host: 'mail.your-server.de',
   port: 143,
   tls: true,
   tlsOptions: {
       rejectUnauthorized: false,
       secureProtocol: 'TLS_method'//TLSv1_2_method should work
     },
   authTimeout: 3000
 }
};




imaps.connect(config).then((connection) => {
 return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(() => {
   const searchCriteria = ['ALL'];
   const fetchOptions = { bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)'], struct: true };
   return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions);
 }).then((messages) => {
   console.log(`You have ${messages.length} messages `);
 }).then(() => {
   connection.end();
 });
}).catch((err) => {
 console.error(err);
});
```

Here the complete error message:

```
Error: D8080000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:

    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/js_stream_socket:77:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  reason: 'wrong version number',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER',
  source: 'socket'
}
```

Comment: TLS is usually on port 993.  If you need to use 143 you usually want _StartTLS_.  According to the hetzner docs they support TLS on 993, so you should probably use that.    If you want to use starttls, it looks like the option is 'autotls: required'

Comment: You are right with the port! I need to use **993**. Now Iam getting a different error: _"Error: Error in IMAP command UID FETCH: Too long argument (0.001 + 0.017 + 0.016 secs)."_  Maybe it receives to many mails at once or it takes to long to fetch them. I set the `limit` parameter in the fetch options to 1 and `connTimeout: 120000` in the config but still getting this error. 
However it worked with the "node-imap" package and the script here **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247207/how-to-read-and-save-attachments-using-node-imap)** from @christiaan-westerbeek